# DrJava and error using LocalDateTime

Tags: java, macos, terminal, compiler-errors, drjava

I am using DrJava on a mac (on the latest java update) and having trouble getting `LocalDateTime` to work. I've imported `java.time.*` but I get an 
error message *"package java.time does not exist"*.
How can I get `LocalDateTime` to compile on DrJava? Alternatively is there another program I can use? Using terminal is an option but I have tried and failed to set it up.

Comment: Please provide us an actual error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
//use:
import java.time.*;

//not: 
package java.time.*;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified! I am using import java.time.*;